# Snowflake - Merge conditions

Tags: merge, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

i have 2 tables, first one only contain new rows (some of them maybe already be in the destination table) and the second one have all the history of this transactional data.

I'm doing a typical Merge in which i "join" by the primary key, if the row already exists, update the existing row, if not, inserts in the destination table.

But the thing is that the new rows that i need to analyze may be in a certain period of time in the past (process timestamp) on the full table so i don't need to analyze all the table, instead met some criteria to limit the destination table and then apply the merge, how can i achieve this? On the same ON condition besides de "join" can i apply the filter conditions there? And if so, applies both conditions at the same time? (join through primary keys and filter the data that not apply?)

Thanks

Example data:

```
table_1:

col1                    col2                        col3
100                     '2023-01-01 00:00:00'       'Data id 100'
101                     '2024-01-01 01:00:00'       'Data id 101'
102                     '2024-01-01 02:00:00'       'Data id 102'
103                     '2024-01-01 03:00:00'       'Data id 103'
104                     '2024-01-01 04:00:00'       'Data id 104'

table_2:
col1                    col2                        col3
101                     '2024-02-09 01:00:00'       'New data id 101'
104                     '2024-02-09 01:00:00'       'New data id 104'


And of course the result is:
col1                    col2                        col3
100                     '2023-01-01 00:00:00'       'Data id 100'
101                     '2024-02-09 01:00:00'       'New data id 101'
102                     '2024-01-01 02:00:00'       'Data id 102'
103                     '2024-01-01 03:00:00'       'Data id 103'
104                     '2024-02-09 01:00:00'       'New data id 104'
```

But the question is if it's possible inside the merge to filter for example in table_1 only the rows that are greater than the timestamp '2023-01-01 00:00:00', i had to previously have micropartitions sets to this col2 to apply this filter in an efficiently way?

Comment: Hi to give a correct response can you please send us the table strucutre with some sample rows, on what you have provided you can have the conditions in the MERGE When not matched and ...your date condition.

Comment: Hi @HimanshuKandpal, the script is something like this: MERGE INTO DB.SCHEMA.table_1 tab1 USING 
(WITH xx AS (
SELECT col1 as id2, col2 as timestamp2,col3 as data2
FROM DB.SCHEMA.table_2)
,some_transformations AS (
SELECT id2, timestamp2, data2
FROM xx)
SELECT id2, timestamp2, data2
FROM some_transformations) AS tab2 
ON tab1.id1 = tab2.id2
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET tab1.timestamp1 = tab2.timestamp2, tab1.data1 = tab2.data2
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (id1, timestamp1, data1) VALUES (tab2.id2, tab2.timestamp2, tab2.data2);

Comment: Added some example data above

Comment: Don't put code in the comments. Edit your question instead

Answer (score 2):

If I read behind the comment you are wanting to avoid loading all of the target table, and Snowflake will avoid partitions, that do not have the data you are looking for.

So lets create some partitions to test with:

```
create or replace table data_test(seq number, val text, extra text);

insert into data_test 
select 
    seq8() as s, 
    s::text || '_A',
    randstr(128, random())
from table(generator(ROWCOUNT => 10000000));
```

now to see it parititon worked:

```
select sum(seq) from data_test where seq > (6*1000*1000)
```

[image]

excellent, we have "data" where old records (low seq) are like old dates you have. So now we can do a MERGE on it, and see if it loads all the data, and how to avoid that.

I going to use clones, as I suspect the MERGES will be messy (ruin the order of the table, thus to avoid that, we will work will clones while testing).

first two rows of data that are newish and very new:

```
create or replace table new_data(id number, new_val text) as 
    select * from values 
      (6000000,'NEW_B'), 
      (60000000,'NEW_B');
```

then clone:

```
create table data_test_a CLONE data_test;
```

and merge:

```
MERGE INTO data_test_a as t1 USING new_data AS t2 
    ON t1.seq = t2.id
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET
        t1.val = t2.new_val 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT (seq, val, extra) 
    VALUES (t2.id, t2.new_val, 'fake data');
```

| number of rows inserted | number of rows updated |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |

and looking at the stats, the partitions scanned is low, as we might hope:

[image]

so, this implies, for dates, also, the "old partitions" should not get touched. IF and only if, your big table in already clustered on the date column. If your data is not naturally or non-naturally ordered, all partitions will need to be loaded.

Comment: Thank you very much Simeon, so i need to check if the destination table is partitioned by the date column in order to be able to only scan the information that matches the join, thanks!

Comment: there is no "partitioning" just clustering (which really just mean order of data) and the major way data is naturally cluster in insert order, or resorting the table.

Answer (score 0):

you can try some thing like this.

-- untested

```
 MERGE INTO DB.SCHEMA.table_1 tab1 
 USING (WITH xx AS ( SELECT col1 as id2, col2 as timestamp2,col3 as data2 FROM DB.SCHEMA.table_2) ,some_transformations AS 
    ( SELECT id2, timestamp2, data2 FROM xx) SELECT id2, timestamp2, data2 FROM some_transformations)
    AS tab2 ON tab1.id1 = tab2.id2 
    
    WHEN MATCHED  AND  col2 > to_date('2023-01-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mi:ss')  THEN UPDATE SET tab1.timestamp1 = tab2.timestamp2, tab1.data1 = tab2.data2 
    
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (id1, timestamp1, data1) VALUES (tab2.id2, tab2.timestamp2, tab2.data2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not see your requirement to use merge statement, instead simple join statement will give result

```
select t1.col1
      , coalesce(t2.col2, t1.col2) as col2
      , coalesce(t2.col3, t1.col3) as col3
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2
on t1.col1 = t2.col1;
```